# Referencing local jQuery.sap.storage initialized in onInit in other functions

Tags: sapui5

I'm attempting to use local storage to store variables used throughout a workflow. I initialize the local storage in the onInit function of my controller as shown below.

```
onInit: function () {       
        var data = {
                "testItem" : [{
                    "priority" : 1,
                    "title" : "test1"
                }]
            }

        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
        oModel.setData(data);
        this.getView().setModel(oModel, "testModel");

        jQuery.sap.require("jquery.sap.storage");
        var oStorage = jQuery.sap.storage(jQuery.sap.storage.Type.local);

        if(oStorage.get("myLocalData")){
            var oData = oStorage.get("myLocalData");
            oModel.setData(oData);
        }
}
```

Once this has been initiated it, how do I access that storage within other functions like an addItem function below?

```
addItem: function(evt){
            var oView=this.getView();
            var newItem = oView.byId("input").getValue();       
            var oModel = oView.getModel("testModel");
            var oNew = {  
                    testItem : {"priority" : 6, "title" :newItem } 
            };  
            var oData = oModel.getData();  

            oData.agendaItem.push(oNew);  
            oModel.refresh(true);  

            oStorage.put("myLocalData", oData);  //this is where I'm unsure

    }
```

Everything else (however hacky ;) ) works up to this point but I can't seem to wrap my head around accessing this local storage. Can I bind it with sap.ui.core or is it persistent in that my initial call in onInit is pointless and local storage is accessible at any point?

I appreciate your patience with me as I'm extremely new to the SAPUI5 library.

Comment: You could use `localSorage-api` as well.. That would be even easier..

Answer (score 0):

Ok so its as easy as it sounds. Using the line

```
jQuery.sap.storage(jQuery.sap.storage.Type.local).put("myLocalData", oData);
```

Puts the data in the local storage. Cheers!